# Force JScrollBar to scroll to line head

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, jscrollbar

I am dealing with `JEditorPane` to display HTML documents and I created a button which scroll me to next view port every time I click it, "as if I am turning a page of a book".

However, sometimes I see a part of a line at the top of the view port, so is there any way to force `JScrollBar` to scroll to ahead of a line?

I tried `setBlockIncrement()` member method but it didn't work at all.

Here you are my best attempt:

```
//get the visible rectangle as well as the most bottom right point. 
Rectangle rec = jEditorPane1.getVisibleRect();
Point pt = new Point((int)rec.getX() +(int)rec.getWidth(),(int)rec.getY() +      (int)rec.getHeight());
// get the offset of the most bottom right point 
int off = jEditorPane1.viewToModel(pt);
try {
//get next viewable rectangle and scroll to it 
rec = jEditorPane1.modelToView(off+100);
rec.height = jEditorPane1.getVisibleRect().height;
jEditorPane1.scrollRectToVisible(rec);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of your best attempt).

Comment: BTW - what should happen if a line has an image embedded, and the image height is greater that the viewable height of the view port?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the viewport is full screen and I am editing  customized epub files. However; if there is an image as you described then the only thing is to start the viewport with a line or an image however its long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess you have a position in the Document you want to show. You can get visible rect of the position using modelToView() method. and use the y position to set your viewport. E.g. use scrollRectToVisible passing the y and viewport height in the rectangle parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am already using modelToView() and scrollRectToVisible() methods, but in my situation the font is resizable, and sometimes apart of line displayed at the bottom of the viewport, so if i scroll with the height of viewport this part of line will appear at the top of the viewport again???.

Comment: I think yes. The caret rect height = row height so no matter which fonts are used in the row.